# Is there a story about Benjamin Franklin inviting a business competitor into his home to show how meager he is willing to live in order to win?

Tags: quotes, business-history

All my life I have had this distinct memory of writing a paper on Benjamin Franklin back in grade school, and a story where he had brought some business competitor of his into his home and showed him a blanket next to the hearth with water and bread... and said something to the effect of: "I can live quite happily on just this... can you/are you willing to subsist on less? That will be the only way to beat me"

I've been trying to figure out how to google this for years... and I've never been successful. It's probably not even Franklin.. it probably has nothing to do with anything I wrote/read in grade school... but I cannot for the life of me figure out where I got that memory.

Can anyone help?